# Issue with deleting selected records in Django after update to 1.8.7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

After updating Django to 1.8.7 I can't delete records from backend using selecting

I have following exception

```
NoReverseMatch at /admin/static_assets/staticassetdefinition/
Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'app_label': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'admin/(?P<app_label>projects|accounts|static_assets|imagelibrary|pages|sites|messaging|omss_auth|system|auth|tastypie)/$']
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://192.168.59.100/admin/static_assets/staticassetdefinition/
Django Version: 1.8.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'app_label': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'admin/(?P<app_label>projects|accounts|static_assets|imagelibrary|pages|sites|messaging|omss_auth|system|auth|tastypie)/$']
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 495
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.5
```

.

```
    class StaticAssetDefinitionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [StaticAssetExecutionInline, StaticAssetCustomFieldDefinitionInline]
    list_display = ['name', 'id', 'section', 'type', 'available', 'get_usage_rights', 'upload_execution']
    actions = ['update_previews', 'regenerate_custom_definition_fields', 'check_depends', 'regenerate_default_pdf', 'test_all_executions']
    list_editable = ('available',)
    list_filter = ('available', SectionListFilter, StaticAssetTypeListFilter, UsageRightsFilter)
    search_fields = ('name',)
```

Update:

Same error appears also when I try to access history view of any record from back-end

Any ideas?

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with deleting from a db, you should post the relevant code

Comment: Can you tell me which code do you need? It affects every model which I have in the backend no diffrence my apps as well as sites and auth from Django so I think it must be related to 'app_label'

Comment: Well the error you've shown there has `app_label` as an empty string, so wherever you set that will be the place to start

Comment: yes but the problem is that delete_selected is defined in django I can see it here https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/actions.py
so I'm not setting it in my admin.py

Comment: Are you using the django.contrib.admin or other? Are you using a custom view?

Comment: I'm not using custom view just django.contrib.admin

Comment: @Zgr3doo: `static_assets/staticassetdefinition` is not something provided by the "standard" Django admin. Clearly you are using a third-party library or your own code.

Comment: yes this is my custom app but its just example as I said in the comment above same error appear when I try to delete any record from any model so even from 'django.contrib.auth' or 'django.contrib.sites'

Comment: @Zgr3doo: the error is happening at `/admin/static_assets/staticassetdefinition/`, please show us the code behind that url

Comment: Maybe a bug in some get_absolute_url() function? Anyway it's a failing reverse() call

Comment: yes for some reason it expect app_label as kwargs

Comment: What version did you upgrade from?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#id2

Comment: @MadWombat its update from 1.6 can you explain me a bit more how app_name could affect my app

Comment: Not sure, it seemed like it might have been relevant. Can you paste the part of your urls.py where you include admin? Are you doing anything fancy with the admin? Like custom admin views or something?

Comment: Just this `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),` I also find out that same error appear when I enter certain record details and try to access history view

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that delete_selected_confirmation.html template was overridden in main app I just overlooked this.